# How can I perform a call using VoIP and play an audio file with Python?

Tags: python, sip, voip

My goal is to perform a call using VoIP and play an audio file (no matter what format) with Python and record the call. I found some libraries but their documentation is unclear and they don't seem to be maintained. I have also tried using external utilities like `sipcli`. This worked but I want to have more control over calling and I'd like not to depend on external software.
P.S. I need it to both work on Linux and on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you explored Pjsip python module.

https://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm

python example:

https://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/pjsip-apps/src/python/samples/call.py

Comment: Looking good, but the installation is really messy. I would love to see a library, that I can install simply using `pip`.

Comment: PJSIP is a free and open source multimedia communication library written in C language implementing standard based protocols such as SIP, SDP, RTP, STUN, TURN, and ICE. it has one of the best feature set for a VOIP call.